# Accessing requirejs module from <script> tag

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jupyter-notebook, requirejs

I currently have a requirejs module that lives on a remote server such as the below that defines some backbone views, models

```
define(['...'], function() {
   ......
   return {
     model : suggestion_model,
     view : suggestion_view
   };
});
```

that is being dynamically loaded in another file as such

```
let script = $("<script>").attr({
src: "http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/autocomplete/autocomplete-model-view.js",
});
console.log(script);
$("head:first").append(script);
```

I see that the file is loaded, when I go to my  tag but I can't access the module to be used in any of the code.

How could I go about actually accessing these defined requirejs module in some other files?

Comment: Are you sure your code is loaded on the browser after `$("head:first").append(script);` is executed? Try checking if `define` or `require` exist in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to access remote requirejs modules by injecting them directly in a script tag. You can try the below steps to access them.

Assuming we have a remote module named `remotemodule`

```
define(['remotemodule'], function() {
   return {
     model : function(){
       return "Im a remote model";
     },
     view : function(){
       return "Im a remote view";
     }
   };
});
```

To access it in your browser..

You need to add `requirejs` script into your html first.

```
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This should give you a global object `require`. You can call the `config` function on `require` to define the `remotemodule` by specifying the `path` to the script.

```
require.config({
            paths: {
                "remotemodule": "https://raggedlostcone.nithinthampi.repl.co/"
            }
        });
```

And then you can call `require(["remotemodule"], function callback)` to load the script. Here the callback is executed once the script is loaded.

```
require(["remotemodule"], function(loaded_script){
            console.log(loaded_script);
            document.getElementById("remotemodule").innerText = loaded_script.model();
        })
```

A simple demo below.

```js
require.config({
            paths: {
                "remotemodule": "https://raggedlostcone.nithinthampi.repl.co/"
            }
        });
        
        require(["remotemodule"], function(loaded_script){
            console.log(loaded_script);
            document.getElementById("remotemodule").innerText = loaded_script.model();
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="remotemodule">
        loading...
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to work! I just have one more question, in my remote code, I have something that is using some underscore templates such as 
` template_box = _.template(autocomplete_box)`, but it's complaining that n.replace is not a function. Is this just a code issue with how I'm using the template or is there a missing dependency or something

Comment: specifically it's saying that it's missing an AMD module dependency in my IDE, but throws an uncaught type error in the console.

Comment: also is there anyway to make the require module synchronous instead?

Comment: If you have multiple AMD dependencies in your remote module, You should consider combining them to a single bundle and use it in UI. https://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#setup

Comment: If its a non-AMD module you can use shim config to load the dependencies. Please see the below REPL where I'm using underscore JS in the remote module https://repl.it/@nithinthampi/FrostyJuicyBoard
https://repl.it/@nithinthampi/MountainousGrippingProgramminglanguages